# shuffling classes of two divs

Tags: jquery, html

I have two div in dynamically created tables .

```
 <td>
  <div class='pane1 display'>
      <a href='#' id='part1'><span class='add_field'>Add field</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class='pane2 hidee'>
  </div>
 </td>
```

I want to shuffle the class names of these two when click on Add field of that table like this

```
<td>
  <div class='pane1 hide'>
      <a href='#' id='part1'><span class='add_field'>Add field</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class='pane2 display'>
  </div>
 </td>
```

I tried this

```
$('.entity_table').on('click', '.add_field', function(events){

   $(this).parent().removeClass('display');
   $(this).parent().addClass('hide')
   $(this).parents('td div.pane2').removeClass('hide');
   $(this).parents('td div.pane2').addClass('display');

});
```

can't use document.getElementbyid cus i have to suffle the classes of that table in which it is clicked .

thanx

Comment: And what isn't working exactly ?

Comment: pane2 class is not changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pointing to the parent of the `span` tag (the one you set the event listener on), wich was the `a` tag. You wanted to reach the parent of the `a` tag...

So you want to get the parent of the parent of the element that was clicked:

```
$('.entity_table').on('click', '.add_field', function(events){

   var $pane1 = $(this).parent().parent(); // store the jquery element for performance and readability matter
   $pane1.removeClass('display').addClass('hide'); // toggle pane1 classes
   $pane1.next('.pane2').removeClass('hide').addClass('display'); //toggle pane2 classes

});
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
$(this).closest('[class^=pane]').toggleClas('display hide');
```

Description:

```
.closest('[class^=pane]')
// select closest div which is starting with pane 
//don't use just parent as it will select the a tag in your html

.toggleClass('display hide') 
// if it is display then it removes display class and adds hide class 
//   and vice versa
```

Comment: I believe that it does. But I just don't like to rely too much on `closest()` method. In this case (and what we know about the DOM), your answer is great anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.entity_table').on('click', '.add_field', function (events) {
    var th = this,
        td = $(th).closest('td'),
        display = $(td).find('.display'),
        hide = $(td).find('.hide');
    $(display).toggleClass('display hide');
    $(hide).toggleClass('display hide');
});
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Eey3s/) here.